# How to continue after gradient descent?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am very new to Data Science and Python. After a few hours of Experimentation, I finally received values for my gradient descent (code below). I am having trouble to plotting bzw. How can I plot the regression line automatically after the algorithm?

```
import numpy as np;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
import csv
import pandas as pd



def gradient_descent(x,y):
    m_curr=b_curr=0
    iterations = 5000
    n=len(x)
    learning_rate = 0.01

    for i in range(iterations):
        y_predicted = m_curr*x + b_curr
        cost = (1/n)*sum([val**2 for val in (y-y_predicted)])
        md = -(2/n)*sum(x*(y-y_predicted))
        bd = -(2/n)*sum(y-y_predicted)
        m_curr = m_curr - learning_rate*md
        b_curr = b_curr - learning_rate*bd

        print("m{}, b{}, cost {}, iteration {}".format(m_curr,b_curr,cost,i))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #Reading data -> Output: DataFrame in float64
    data = pd.read_csv('ex1data1.txt', sep=',', header=None, names=['Feature', 'Label'])
    data.plot(x='Feature', y='Label', kind = 'scatter')

    #separating data frame to 
    feat_vec = pd.DataFrame(data['Feature'])
    label_vec = pd.DataFrame(data['Label'])

    #Finding the Best Fit Line for our given Dataset and convert the df to np.array
    #because it's more convenient for matrix multiplication
    x = np.array(feat_vec)
    y = np.array(label_vec)

    gradient_descent(x,y)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "bzw" in "I have problems to plot bzw"??

Comment: Also, what is the number of features? As it is not straight forward to plot when the number of features are more than 2.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa I expect that the bzw refers to the common mathematical notation for the bias, activations, and weights in a neural network or (in the case of a regression), the intercept, logits, and betas, respectively. Altogether, I'd take that to mean that bzw is the hyperplane.

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem. Some examples of inputs and expected outputs are always useful. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.